# "Key not valid for use in specified state" while trying to Sign a Xml

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0, x509certificate2

### My History:

I need to sign all my `Xml's` before uploading to the government agency.
To sign, I'm using client certificates loaded from the `X509Store`:

```
var repo = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

repo.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

foreach (X509Certificate2 certCurrent in repo.Certificates)
{
    if (!certCurrent.Subject.Equals(subject)) continue;

    if (certCurrent.NotAfter > DateTime.Now)
    {
        repo.Close();
        return certCurrent;
    }
}

repo.Close();
return null;
```

And `SignedXml` `(XmlDocument xmlDoc, string id, X509Certificate2 certificate)`:

```
var refer = new Reference();
refer.Uri = "#" + id;
refer.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
refer.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());

var signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.PrivateKey;
signedXml.AddReference(refer);

signedXml.ComputeSignature();

var key = new KeyInfo();
key.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate));
signedXml.KeyInfo = key;

//Final signature xml block.
XmlElement signedBlock = signedXml.GetXml();
```

### Problem:

One of my clients changed his PC password and out of nothing the second block of code throws this error:

```
Message - 
    Key not valid for use in specified state.
Type - 
    CryptographicException
Source - 
    mscorlib
TargetSite - 
    System.Security.Cryptography.SafeProvHandle CreateProvHandle(System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters, Boolean)
StackTrace - 
    at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
    at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()
    at Util.SignXml.Sign(XmlDocument xmlDoc, String id, X509Certificate2 certificate, String& error)
```

It says that the `getter` of the `PrivateKey` is throwing that exception.
Later, I'll try to install that certificate again, with the `Exportable` checked.

PS: `Windows Server 2003`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my client changed his password, the `certificate` needed to be installed again.

*That's it.*

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new test certificate seems to have solved the problem. This blog post pointed me in the right direction.

Open the properties page for the project that is giving the error.
Click the Signing tab.
Click Create Test Certificate.
Enter a password and click OK.
This got things working again for me.